# Create table in HTML using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've an array of `string`, I need to display it using `ng-repeat` of `AngularJS` like the following screenshot:

[image]

I have an idea, to "play" in the index-s to display that:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="param in params">
  <tr>
    <td>{{param.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

That for every row I'll display the first item, and to display in the same row every ( $index, $index + 3, $index + 6)

Is there any other ideas, or an idea how to do that?

Comment: "and to display in the same row every ( $index, $index + 3, $index + 6)". That's not the same logic as the image that is shown, which evenly splits the array into 3 columns.

Comment: you could solve this with CSS3 coumn-count or a different CSS approach if you can't use CSS3 for browser compatibility reasons (http://pterkildsen.com/2012/12/08/css3-columns-in-internet-explorer-7-8-and-9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/cmdm1dhL/1/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in [] | range:Math.ceil(items.length/tableColumns)">
            <td ng-repeat="item in items | everyNth:row:Math.ceil(items.length/tableColumns)">{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);
        for (var i=0; i<total; i++)
            input.push(i);
        return input;
    };
});

myApp.filter('everyNth', function() {
    return function(input, row, nth) {
        var output = [];
        for (var i=row; i<input.length; i+=nth)
            output.push(input[i]);
        return output;
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var numberOfItems = 14;
    $scope.items = [];
    for (var i=1; i<=numberOfItems; i++)
        $scope.items.push('Item ' + i);

    $scope.tableColumns = 3;

    $scope.Math = window.Math;
}

</script>
```